# Real analysis: Continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

Define $f: [0,1) \cup [2,3] \rightarrow [0,2]$ by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x \in [0,1) \\ x-1 & x \in [2,3] \end{cases}$$

Is the function continuous at $x=1$? Is the function continuous at $x=2$?

For example, at $x=2$, continuity means for all $\epsilon$ we can find $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$ when $|x-2|<\delta$. But $f(x)$ is undefined in $(2-\delta,2)$. Do we consider $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$ to be true or false?

Comment: The condition is for $x$ in the domain of $f$. Yes it is continuous there (i.e. at 2)

Comment: The function is not defined at $x=1$, so continuity is out of the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the definition of continuity cannot apply to points outside the domain of definition. It is meaningless to ask whether $f$ is continuous at $x=1$.

At $x=2$, since $f$ is undefined in any left neighborhood of $2$, the definition of continuity boils down to

**Definition.** For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $2 \leq x <2+\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(2)| < \varepsilon$.

It is now very easy to solve 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
1-\varepsilon < x-1 < 1+\varepsilon \\
2 \leq x \leq 3 \quad\text{or}\quad 0 \leq x <1
\end{array}
\right.
$$ and check that such a $\delta>0$ exists: you can even choose $\delta=\varepsilon$.